# Is there any function in matlab to create stationary series?

Tags: matlab, time-series, generate-series

Is there any function in matlab to create stationary series? Or somewhere specific that I can get this kind of series? I'm implementing a method and I think the lack of a stationary series is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to go on here, please try to be more specific w.r.t. the "method" and the "series"... A common error is to use OLS regression on a non-stationary process in which case results could be spurious. To avoid this, when a variable is suspected of being non-stationary, a transformation of that variable can sometimes break that non-stationarity. For example, an autocorrelated AR(1) process with a unit root (non-stationary) will yield the (stationary) innovation if you subtract two successive values from each other (e.g. using the diff function).

To answer your question more directly (but perhaps less usefully), any Matlab function generating a random number without changing the distribution through time will generate a "stationary process"... e.g. `plot(randn(1000,1))` shows a "process" which represents pure innovations. If these innovations were in an AR(1) with a unit root (i.e. X(t+1)=X(t)+u) process we could get something like:

```
AR1 = cumsum(u);
innov=diff(AR1);
plot([AR1(2:end),innov])
```

As you can see, the AR1 process is non-stationary since it has a unit root. trivially, x is in fact the innovation, but "reverse engineering" it using diff just shows that in this case you can recover from the non-stationary series something stationary.

Finally, a common test to look for non-stationarity is the augmented Dickey Fuller test (a unit root test), which is implemented in Matlab: https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/adftest.html